# Sql Server migration, other datetime

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, utc, getdate

I have a website which was located in UTC + 1 (The SQL SERVER).

I have migrated the website, and now I have in UTC - 8(The SQL SERVER).

So I have 9 hours of difference.

I have an automatic publication of post based in the beginning of the day.

So I usually post one post each day at 0.00 in UTC + 1 , but now it is publishing 9 hours later...

All my select clauses end with:

```
select id, title, content 
from articles 
**where dateScheduled <= getdate()**
```

If I wanted to publish a post the 25 of January, I need to wait until it is 25 of January in the UTC - 8, but I want to be publish 9 hours earlier==> when it is 25 of January in UTC + 1.

What do you think that it can be the best way to do it?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused on what you're asking. Are you trying to post these records at midnight local time instead of midnight UTC time?

Have you looked into something like this:

```
DATEADD(hh,DATEDIFF(hh,GETUTCDATE(),GETDATE()),dateScheduled)
```

The DATEDIFF pull how many hours local time is away from UTC + 0 time and then add that difference to a date column. This is useful if your timezone practices DST so you don't have to change a hard coded -8 value.

Let me know if this helps. If not, clarify what you're trying to do and I'll look at it.

Comment: So, if I understand your solution:
if the SQL Server is in the UTC + 8, this sentence is adding 8 hours to the dateScheduled?

Comment: No, that command is taking the difference between the server's local time and the UTC time in order to pad the datescheduled column. This would be used if your datescheduled files as local time (server or your local time vs in the UTC time format). We are in the process of moving our time columns to UTC format to ease pains like you're experiencing with timezones and DST.

Comment: Could you clarify the last statement from your original post, that would help me figure out what you're trying to do. "If I wanted to publish a post the 25 of January, I need to wait until it is 25 of January in the UTC - 8, but I want to be publish 9 hours earlier==> when it is 25 of January in UTC + 1." What time on January 25th are you looking to post, UTC + 1?

Comment: Ok, the most important: I want to post the records in UTC + 1 time. And the SQL Server is in UTC - 8.
Thanks!!!!

Comment: Ok.. does this work: WHERE dateScheduled < = DATEADD(hh,-9,GETDATE())? That will subtract 9 hours from the server's date/time which should bring it to your local time zone. You have to watch out for DST though!

Comment: I have done: WHERE dateScheduled < = DATEADD(hh,9,GETDATE()) and it works. What is DST? DO you have any good link where it is explained?

Thank you!

Comment: DST = Daylight savings time. Your timezone may or may not practice DST (mine does) and the timezone your SQL server is housed might practice this. What that means for you is that the above query could be an hour off during DST. Glad to hear this worked!